# How to send extra content on next page in pdf conversion with jspdf and html2canvas in angular 15

Tags: javascript, angular, jspdf, html2canvas, angular15

This is my pdfconversion() method in ts file.

```
 public exportToPdf() {
const element = this.pdfTable.nativeElement;


html2canvas(element,{ scale: 3 }).then((canvas) => {
  const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 1.0);
  // const pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4'); // A4 size page of PDF
  const pdf = new jsPDF({
    orientation: 'portrait',
    unit: 'mm',
    format:[canvas.width, canvas.height],

  }); 
  
 

  const position = 0;

  pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'html', 4, position, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  pdf.save('file.pdf'); // Generated PDF
});
```

}

This one is working fine. But as the content increases beyond the limit of the page it cuts the extra content. I am also some properties like pageSize that is showing undefined. So please tell me the way that can send the extra content to next page.